# How to match all paths in Akka HTTP

Tags: scala, akka-http

Most Akka HTTP examples show it is really easy to define `Routes` using  `path`.

I have the following (slightly simplified) from the [introductory example](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala/http/introduction.html#routing-dsl-for-http-servers),

```
val route =
  path("hello") {
    complete(
      HttpEntity(
        ContentTypes.`text/html(UTF-8)`,
        "<h1>Say hello to akka-http</h1>"))
  }
```

However, the above only works for "/hello" and I want to match all possible paths or URLs, not just "hello".  The empty string, `""`, only matches the root path and `"*"` matches the literal path "/*".  The parameter to `path` is required and cannot simply be omitted.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The there are a lot of ways this can be accomplished.  I believe the following shows some ways ordered most preferred to least preferred.

#### Use other types of directives

The simplest solution requires knowing that the Route can be any [Directive](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala/http/routing-dsl/directives/index.html), not only [path directives](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala/http/routing-dsl/directives/path-directives/index.html#overview-of-path-directives).
Thus, the original example could be modified to achieve the desired results by just by dropping the `path` completely:

```
val route =
  complete(
    HttpEntity(
      ContentTypes.`text/html(UTF-8)`,
      "<h1>Say hello to akka-http</h1>"))
```

#### Use a different `PathMatcher` with `path`

`path` does not actually take a `String` as a parameter.  `path("hello")` is actually `pathPrefix(_segmentStringToPathMatcher("hello"))` after implicit conversion.  The desired outcome is possible using different arguments of type `PathMatcher`.

You can use `Remaining` which matches everything left.

```
val route =
  path(Remaining) { _ =>
    complete(
      HttpEntity(
        ContentTypes.`text/html(UTF-8)`,
        "<h1>Say hello to akka-http</h1>"))
  }
```

Or you can use a regular expression:

```
val route =
  path(".*".r) { _ =>
    complete(
      HttpEntity(
        ContentTypes.`text/html(UTF-8)`,
        "<h1>Say hello to akka-http</h1>"))
  }
```

Both of the above make available the match and thus you have the additional ignored lambda argument.

#### Use `pathPrefix("")` instead of `path("")`

According to [the documentation for `path`](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala/http/routing-dsl/directives/path-directives/path.html#description) empty string, `""`, does in behave a little like a wildcard in that will always match a string.  However, `path` requires an exact match (the entire string be consumed by the match) but the empty string only completely consumes the empty string.  Since `pathPrefix` only requires the beginning of the string to match, not the entire string be consumed, the following works:

```
val route =
  pathPrefix("") {
    complete(
      HttpEntity(
        ContentTypes.`text/html(UTF-8)`,
        "<h1>Say hello to akka-http</h1>"))
  }
```